# How can I set a CoAP post request Body with a requestparameter and a File?

Tags: java, coap, californium

I want to upload a file from a CoAP client by using the californium standard forwarded proxy to a server which supports http-communication.

Is there an alternative with CoAP to build a post Request with a name of the RequestParameter and a payload contents the Value of file?

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CoAP (and so Californium) focus on efficiency for small payloads. POST files will not be the domain of CoAP at all.
If you really want that, just load the payload from the file and POST that. Ensure, you configured the MAX_RESOURCE_BODY_SIZE in Californium.properties according your requirements. If you use Californium on both sides, both need to be configured.
Alternatively, you may disable the "transparent blockwise" using a 0 MAX_RESOURCE_BODY_SIZE. That will then require, that you handle the single blocks and block-option on your own.

Comment: Thank for your Answer . I updated the Parameters as you suggested and and  I can  push  the  payload  successfully.

Comment: Sounds not too bad!